# Right border cutting into bottom border

Tags: html, css

How do you fix the grey border line so that it comes right down to the bottom of the green highlight instead of cutting off halfway?

I have provided my code below at [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmtsJ).

Thanks in advance for your help :)

[image: A picture of what it looks like]

html

```
<div id="status_bar">
                <div class="admin_status_box">
                    <ul>
                        <a href="admin.php" class="active">View & Delete posts </a>
                        <a href="admin-delete-members.php">View & Delete members </a>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
```

css

```
#status_bar {
    width: 700px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #efefef;
    float: left;
}

.admin_status_box {
    background: #efefef;    
    height: 60px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d6d6d6;

}

.admin_status_box ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

.admin_status_box li {
    text-decoration: none;

}

.admin_status_box a {
    text-decoration: none;

    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;

    float: left;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d6d6d6;


}

.admin_status_box a.active {

border-bottom: 10px solid #619e4c;
}

.admin_status_box a:hover {
    background: #fff;

}
```

Comment: You can't 'fix' the border to do what you want; this behaviour is by design: HTML elements' borders meet at a 45 degree angle.

Comment: If you add `li` elements and put the border on those, everything works as expected. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your HTML should be valid by actually using `<li>` tags. Next, you need to know, that borders meet at an angle and the corners are interpolated. A nice example is

```
div.test { 
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: 20px 0 5px 0;
  border-color: #000;
  border-style: solid;
 }
```

So, in order to fix your problem, you need to assign the borders to different elements. If you insert the `<li>` tags you have two elements to work with. See the ***[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qDAlB)*** for the following code.

```
.admin_status_box li {
  border-right: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.admin_status_box a.active {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #619e4c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `li` elements to be the first child of a `ul` element. If you put each `a` element inside of a `li` element, you can then set the border on the `li` element and the border have the desired result. After this is done, make sure you remove the 1px border from `.admin_status_box`

It may take a bit of CSS to get them positioned exactly how you would want them.

**[See this edited codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmhon)**

**EDIT** Typo

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a separate div to act as the bar. You can't tell the side border to shorten because that's the behavior it's set. Best bet is to use the div you have commented out as green_box.

Answer (score 0):

I just corrected the html, displayed the li's `inline-block` and added the border bottom to the li's instead of the link. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hvcBI